# "a place where I could belong" vs "a place I could belong"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, pronouns, phrase-meaning

Regarding the sentence *I feel like that company is a place where I could belong and contribute to with my goals and values*

I'm concerned if adding *where* is necessary to convey the **idea of feeling like you could belong in a specific institution**. I've seen other sentences with similar meaning without it but to me without *where* it sounds incomplete.

Also, I'm not sure if, to express such meaning, the correct phrasing such contain "I could belong **in** and contribute to"

Which one conveys such meaning the best, "a place where I could belong" or "a place I could belong"?

Comment: "Where” is optional, though I’d say most people would include it. “Where” means “in/at x place” so whether or not it's included we understand “I could belong in/at x place”. You can say: "I feel like that company is a place (where) I could belong and contribute to with my goals and values". The object of the preposition "to" is understood as "a place"

Answer (score 1):

"A place I could belong" is awkward, and you should probably avoid it. To see why, consider the following rephrasings:

> If there's a place where you belong, then you belong at that place.
>
> If there's a place you belong, then you belong that place.

You can't belong a place. You can belong *at* or *to* or *in* a place. So the most correct form would be "a place at which I belong" or "a place to which I belong" or "a place in which I belong", and since *where* implies *at*, "a place where I belong" is proper.

That said, "a place I belong" is used here and there. So are the other forms ("place we belong", "place they belong", etc.). If I look at Ngrams and squint, it's used as much as about a quarter of the time. If I search, I find "a place I belong" predominantly in song lyrics, though, and songs are known for taking a few shortcuts with the language to make the meter fit.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. Then is it correct to say "a place where I could belong in and contribute to"?

Comment: "A place where I could belong in" is too much - either "where" or "in" should be struck (but not both).  ....Style-wise, the whole clause feels a bit wordy. Either of the phrases "where I could belong" or "I could contribute to" might imply the other, in context, so I would try to avoid the other. But that, again, is a style consideration.